# Why does my Gmail icon have balloons?

Tags: gmail

I don't think there's a special occasion. This is either April fools or the day I joined Gmail?

From the icon itself:

[image]

Crop from screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gmail celebrates 15-year anniversary. This can be briefly spotted upon login to Gmail for few seconds on loading screen (if you reload your Gmail with **<kbd>F5</kbd>** key)

[image: 0]

> Back in 2004, email looked a lot different than it does today. Inboxes
>   were overtaken by spam, and there was no easy way to search your inbox
>   or file messages away. Plus, you had to constantly delete emails to
>   stay under the storage limit. We built Gmail to address these
>   problems, and it’s grown into a product that 1.5 billion users rely on
>   to get things done every day. Today, on Gmail’s 15 birthday, we’re
>   taking a look back and sharing where we’re headed next.
>
> On April 1, 2004 we launched Gmail (despite the timing, not a joke).
>   It had the power of Google Search built right in and grouped your
>   messages into conversation threads, making it easier to find and reply
>   to them. You could also store 1GB of data for free - nearly 100 times
>   what was available at the time. No wonder the world thought it was a
>   prank.
>
> **https://blog.google/products/gmail/hitting-send-on-the-next-15-years-of-gmail/**

---

Also, it's worth to mention that Gmail got updated with two more futures:

- **[schedule delivery of messages](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/15-years-and-counting-making-gmail-work-faster-and-smarter-for-businesses)**
- **[respond to a comment thread in Google Docs/Sheets](https://www.blog.google/products/gmail/take-action-and-stay-up-to-date-with-dynamic-email-in-gmail/)**

Comment: Pressing the F5 key does nothing for me.

Comment: @LS if you are on NB the combo is FN+F5

Answer (score 2):

It's because of google's 15th birthday.  If you reload the page balloons quickly show up saying "google's 15th birthday"

Answer (score 1):

It may be because April 1, 2019 is the 15th anniversary of Gmail.